# Reading a Single Item from a custom web config section

Tags: c#, config

I have created a custom config section to store a list of of items. The config is as follows:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="Items" type="namespace.Items, namespace"/>
</configSections>
<Items>
    <Item name="Item1"/>
    <Item name="Item2"/>
</Items>
```

I have also created my own configuration handler as follows:

```
public class ItemConfigurationHandler : IConfigurationSectionHandler
{
    public ItemConfigurationHandler()
    {
    }

    public object Create(object parent, object configContext, System.Xml.XmlNode section)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        System.Xml.XmlNodeList items = section.SelectNodes("Item");

        foreach (XmlNode i in items)
        {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.Name = i.Attributes["name"].InnerText;
            items.Add(item);
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

This is currently working fine and I can retrieve a list of items from the config as follows:

```
List<Item> ts = (List<Item>)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Items");
```

I am wondering however, is it possible to just retrieve a single item? For example, if I wanted the details of "Item1" only. I can successfully retrieve the list and then filter where name = "Item1" but this means loading all the XML which seems a bit much if only want one item from the list, especially as this list grows, i dont want to load 20 items if I only need one, or is this not much of an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's not a big issue - loading 1 versus 20 you aren't going to see a blip on today's machines unless you have nested XML configurations.

[**ConfigurationManager**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134260) also caches the values, so once you query the config section they remain in memory for subsequent requests. You can use [`ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("Items")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx) to refresh the cache.

Comment: Thanks SliverNinja, I might just stick with filtering the list of items then. As ConfigurationManager caches the values, do you think this is still quicker than storing the values in a separate file and writing my own methods to parse the XML? (I suppose it depends on how I parse it?)

Comment: It depends on how complex your configuration is, how much flexibility you need, and whether you perform your own caching. As a future maintainer of your code - I'd prefer you don't reinvent the wheel (*stick with .NET configuration support*). There's a reason we have standards, but there all always reason to bend the rules for edge cases.

Comment: @SliverNinja is this an edge case?

Comment: Not from the description provided above. The parsing could be optimized by the returned object type. Instead of using `List<Item>` it could use a `SortedDictionary<string, Item>` so that lookups are trivially fast. For nested XML configurations, you can always use [`sectionGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228114.aspx)

Comment: I've decided to stick with what I have at the moment and filter. I will look at SortedDictionary too for the faster lookups! For this I assume I would use the Item Name for the key? As that is what I will use to lookup the item? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you need to store these items in the `web.config`? The `web.config` file, conceptually, is meant for configuration settings. If you plan to programatically read/write to this file, could you store the data in your own **custom** xml file and parse the data from there?

**EDIT** : Since your comment suggests you'd like to keep these items in the web.config, I don't believe it would be a major issue to retrieve the entire list and iterate through to find the necessary value. You could add values to the `<appSettings>` tag and access them individually as well.

e.g.:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="item1" value="item1 value"/>
    <add key="item2" value="item2 value"/>
     . . .
    <add key="item20" value="item20 value"/>
</appSettings>
```

Access it like so:

```
var item1Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["item1"];
```

Though, if you're only reading this information I'm unclear as to why you're set on putting them in the configuration file to begin with. It might be easier just to define these variables within the code.

Comment: Hi Sam, I considered that approach but I don't need to write to the file so thought I keep everything together in the config. If there is no way to read out a single value then I shall take this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the edit. I will be most likely be expanding these items with more attributes in future so a simple "key=>value" approach wont suffice, thus the need for the custom section. The reason I opted for this approach is I am creating a class library that I want to plug into a web app, I don't want to hardcode the items and recompile each time I want to update a value (which would be rare). Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, best of luck with your project!